# How to recursively iterate through ViewParent tree?

Tags: android, recursion, android-view

I have tree of views, looking something like this.

```
-- parent view top
  -- parent view mid 
  -- parent view mid
    -- parent view low
    -- parent view low
      -- child 1
      -- child 2
      -- child 3
```

I want to check from the child level the id of the top parent view to apply some logic there, based on some TouchEvents in child.
Do you know how can I design the recursive function which will allow me to iterate to the top?

I was able with the usage of getParent() method to get to desired Parent, but this solution is not flexible enough for me at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function from child to parent can be done in this way.

```
public void doSomething(View view) {
    // 
    // do something here
    //

    if(view.getParent() != null) 
    {
        doSomething(view.getParent());
    }
}
```

Comment: I had some bad times with solvings the views ids, but this was a good call.